# Filling multiple inputs with randomized values in one button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, random

I am trying to build the user interface for an online character creator app using jQuery. I am trying to randomly generate character stats with one button click. This is my first time using jQuery in a non-trivial application.

The issue is that when I click the button, not numbers are generated inside the forms. If I remove the disabled attribute it still doesn't work, so I know that isn't the problem.

If I was to take a stab at it I would guess $() in jQuery doesn't like taking variables, but if that is the case, I don't know how the right way to do this would be. The example for filling out multiple forms with one click on the jQuery site isn't useful for this purpose since I need to make sure the dice function is called separately to fill each form.

My javascript code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //stats as an array
    stats = ["#smarts", "#rwp", "#driving", "#cool", "#bod", "#luck", "#looks", "#bonk"];

    //roll dice function
    function dice (x, n, y) {
        var result = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            result = result + Math.floor((Math.random() * n) + 1);
        }
        result = result + y;
        return result;
    }

    //roll each stat function
    function rollStats(stats) { 
        for(stat in stats) {
            $(stat).val(dice(1, 6, 0));
        }
    }

    //on button click roll each stat
    $("#stats").click(rollStats(stats));

});
```

And for reference the relevant part of my html form looks like this:

```
  <form class="create-teenager">
      Smarts:
      <input type="number" name="smarts" id="smarts" disabled />
      <br/><br/>

      Relationship with Parents:
      <input type="number" name="rwp" id="rwp" disabled />
      <br/><br/>

      Driving:
      <input type="number" name="driving" id="driving" disabled />
      <br/><br/>

      Cool:
      <input type="number" name="cool" id="cool" disabled />
      <br/><br/>

      Bod:
      <input type="number" name="bod" id="bod" disabled />
      <br/><br/>

      Luck:
      <input type="number" name="luck" id="luck" disabled />
      <br/><br/>

      Looks:
      <input type="number" name="looks" id="looks" disabled />
      <br/><br/>

      Bonk:
      <input type="number" name="bonk" id="bonk" disabled />
      <br/><br/>

      <button id="stats">Roll Stats</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: just out of curiosity is this for a class somewhere?  Questions eerily similiar involving characters in a game an their stats seem to get asked fairly often.  Not nocking you, just wondering.

Comment: No this isn't for a class, jut finished school, but back when I was in it, the only thing we ever programmed for where business applications.

I was suggested it as a good way to practice from a much more experienced Javascript programmer though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I suggest you to pull outside the button from the form or prevent default.

Try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lnyt6c6r/).

```
<form class="create-teenager">
  Smarts:
  <input type="number" name="smarts" id="smarts" disabled />
  <br/><br/>

  Relationship with Parents:
  <input type="number" name="rwp" id="rwp" disabled />
  <br/><br/>

  Driving:
  <input type="text" name="driving" id="driving" />
  <br/><br/>

  Cool:
  <input type="number" name="cool" id="cool"  />
  <br/><br/>

  Bod:
  <input type="number" name="bod" id="bod" disabled />
  <br/><br/>

  Luck:
  <input type="number" name="luck" id="luck" disabled />
  <br/><br/>

  Looks:
  <input type="number" name="looks" id="looks" disabled />
  <br/><br/>

  Bonk:
  <input type="number" name="bonk" id="bonk" disabled />
  <br/><br/>
```

Roll Stats

And try this script

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  //stats as an array
  stats = ["#smarts", "#rwp", "#driving", "#cool", "#bod", "#luck", "#looks", "#bonk"];

  //roll dice function
  function dice (x, n, y) {
      var resultNumber = 0;
      for(i = 0; i < x; i++) {
          resultNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * n) + 1) + y;
      }
      console.log(resultNumber);
      return resultNumber;
  }

  //on button click roll each stat
  $("#stats").click(function() { 
    for(stat in stats) {
        $(stats[stat]).val(dice(1, 6, 0));
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: After comparing my code with yours, it looks like $("#stats").click(); didn't accept my rollStats function for whatever reason.

Not sure why. I would think it would have something to do with scope, but it has no issues with the dice() function.

This definitely solves the problem however.

Answer (score 0):

You are using for in wrong it needs to be:

```
for(stat in stats) {
    $(stats[stat]).val(dice(1, 6, 0));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I kind of had confusion in  syntax with how similar loops work in other languages.